# For loop at an interval?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, setinterval

How would I control the interval that a for loop runs at?

For instance

```
for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
    //do stuff
}
```

But I want the for loop to run every 60ms, not ASAP. Kinda like how `setInterval` works.

Comment: if you want it to work like `setInterval` use `setInterval` itself!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var interval, i = 0;

function dostuff() {
    /* ... logic ... */

    if(i < 5) i++;
    else clearInterval(interval);
}

interval = setInterval(dostuff, 60);
```

Comment: the function `doStuff` has all the properties of a `for` loop now. (index + condition)

Comment: Looks good, I'll try it out and accept your answer if it works correctly.

Comment: Apart of minor typo that I've fixed for you, [looks like it's working just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/QKWGn/). :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard good catch :) That is what happens when you code against the clock to get it submitted before the hoard...

Comment: @Xander great speed, no doubt one of the fastest guns in the west.. you know, there is [serious discussion about this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)! :)